# how to make this lazyload scrolling working with provider

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-provider

it take about 7 days trying make a working example for lazyload listview with provider in flutter with real world example and it's still not working because i think something is missing

**As a note** : the first load , works good and when i scroll it's print (scroll) but nothing happened it's still in the same page
if i try to return **_todolist** variable in the **_onScrollUpdated** it not change page correctly and after three times i see this error

> E/flutter ( 7713): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)]
> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type
> 'List' E/flutter ( 7713): #0      TodoService.fetchTodos
> (package:flutter_todo_provider/services/todo_service.dart:32:21)

json example
https://jsonformatter.org/52c83e

**todos_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:flutter_todo_provider/helpers/http_exception.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_todo_provider/.env.dart';
import 'package:flutter_todo_provider/services/todo_service.dart';

class TodosScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodosScreenState createState() => _TodosScreenState();
}

class _TodosScreenState extends State<TodosScreen> {
  ScrollController _controller;
  List<dynamic> _todoList;
  bool _isLoading ;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_onScrollUpdated);
  }
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(Configuration.AppName),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fetchListItems(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return _listItems(snapshot.data);
            }
            return _buildProgressIndicator();
          }
      ),
    );
  }
  _fetchListItems() async {
    try {
      await Provider.of<TodoService>(context, listen: false).loadNextPage();
      _todoList = Provider.of<TodoService>(context, listen: false).items;
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.showError(e.message);
    }
    return  _todoList ;

  }


  Widget _listItems(data){
    _isLoading =  Provider.of<TodoService>(context, listen: false).isLoading ;
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      itemCount: data.length  ,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(data[index].title),
          subtitle:Text(data[index].content),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.print),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onScrollUpdated() async {
    print("Scroll11");
    var maxScroll = _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
    var currentPosition = _controller.position.pixels;
    if (currentPosition == maxScroll ) {
      try {
        await Provider.of<TodoService>(context, listen: false).loadNextPage();
        _todoList = Provider.of<TodoService>(context, listen: false).items;
```

//   return  _todoList ; if use this line i see the error

```
      } on HttpException catch (e) {
        EasyLoading.showError(e.message);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    _isLoading =  Provider.of<TodoService>(context, listen: false).isLoading ;
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new Opacity(
          opacity: _isLoading ? 1.0 : 00,
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**todo_service.dart**

```
 import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_todo_provider/.env.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_todo_provider/models/todo.dart';
    
    class TodoService with ChangeNotifier {
      bool isLoading = false;
      bool isFetching = false;
      int currentPage = 1;
      int totalRows = 10;
      List<Todo> items = [];
    
    
      loadNextPage() async {
        await fetchTodos(currentPage);
        currentPage++;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      Future fetchTodos(int currentPage) async {
    
        try {
          //404
          var options = Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic ${Configuration.authToken}'
          });
          Map<String, dynamic> qParams = {
            'current_page': currentPage,
          };
          Response  response = await Dio().get('${Configuration.ApiUrl}/todos/my_todos',   options: options, queryParameters: qParams);
          List<dynamic> responseBode =  response.data["data"];
          responseBode.forEach(( dynamic json) {
            items.add(Todo.fromJson(json));
          });
          notifyListeners();
    
        } on DioError catch (e) {
          print("Error Message" + e.response.statusMessage);
          return items=[];
        }
    
    
      }
```

}

Comment: Fetch data from initState, remove FutureBuilder, use Provider/Consumer inside your widget tree instead.

Comment: why i can not use FutureBuilder?

Comment: Because the Future builder will call the async only once and you need to update the widget tree again after the first call. Take a look: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: The problem is that you need Consumer inside your widget tree in ordem to receive notifyListeners and update the tree

Comment: but as documentation future builder has its own state and it's rebuild every time the data changed https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Futures completes only once. There are cases where you change the Future that FutureBuilder is waiting for, resulting in another update. Tomorrow I'll answer with the code. Im using only cellphone today and Its dificult to post code here.

Comment: thank you , i will try without FutureBuilder and will update my question with the new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
class TodoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  // Your service goes here
  // (the class extending ChangeNotifier)
  @override
  _TodoScreenState createState() => _TodoScreenState();
}

class _TodoScreenState extends State<TodoScreen> {
  final TodoService todoService = TodoService();

  ScrollController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_onScrollUpdated);
    loadNextPage();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Configuration.AppName'),
      ),
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: todoService,
        child: Consumer<TodoService>(builder: (_, ctl, __) {
          if (todoService.isLoading) {
            return _buildProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            return _listItems(todoService.items);
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _listItems(data) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(data[index].title),
          subtitle: Text(data[index].content),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.print),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onScrollUpdated() async {
    var maxScroll = _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
    var currentPosition = _controller.position.pixels;
    if (currentPosition == maxScroll) {
      todoService.loadNextPage();
    }
  }
}
```

Note that i didn't make changes to your service. The notifyListeners will do all the job for us.

When you are using Provider, the idea is to keep all your data inside the controller or service (the class that extends ChangeNitifier) and just use the variables with notifyListeners to change the behavior of your screen.

The screen needs to be listening for changes, for this we use the pair ChangeNotifierProvider.value with Consumer(builder: (_, ctl, __) {}).
Use ChangeNotifierProvider in some upper level of the widget tree and use Consumer *only* where you need the widget to be updated. You can even use more than one Consumer, they all just need to be under ChangeNotifierProvider.

Comment: thank you racr0x , but your example not working ,it's not load any data in the first load , it think the problem with the first calling to this service  todoService.loadNextPage(); i think you forget to put it in the initState

Comment: You need to make the first call inside initState. I'll update my answer. I have not tested it, so maybe there are some bugs. It's important for you to understand the idea behind.

Comment: ok thank after i add it it works but still the same error when scroll 3 times ,  E/flutter ( 5783): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'      i think the reason is because i reached the end of results , plz how to handle this

Comment: Use try/catch or handle the response of `Response  response = await Dio().get...`

Comment: no it's not about that , already i use try and catch , i think it's about getting null data after scrolling to the end of results ,how can i handle this

Comment: Handle the response. The response may be empty not throwing exceptions. Look for the content of the response. Check if response.data != null and response.data.hasKey('data'). Then check the data itself.

Comment: thank you , can you give me a hint how to handle reach the end of json results , to prevent another scroll?

Comment: Set some bool to keep track.

Comment: i already have but the issue , how to prevent scrolling ,disable scrolling after complete the results